# Create document when create new folder

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I wonder how to create a PDF or Word document automatically from the repository when I create a new folder in the document library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I mean the technology you wanna use, in a local server, web browser, etc.

Comment: Sure, I'm talking about Alfresco Share.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you exactly mean. Buy I guess it can be done by a rule or behaviour.

Create a rule on the root folder where your folders will be created. Set the incoming type to be folder.
As the action execute a JavaScript.

If you look at the [JavaScript API Cookbook](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JavaScript_API_Cookbook#Create_Document.2C_Make_it_Versionable.2C_Modify_It), there are samples on how to create a file. Creating PDF's or Word from scratch is a bit difficult hence the binary content isn't plain text.

Comment: Maybe I have not explained well, my apologies. 

The reason for my post is to find a way to automatically create a PDF document or text document when you create a new folder in the document library. The Pdf document or word document will be uploaded previously into the repository of the alfresco share.                             

I'll check you link.

Thanks.

Comment: If It's already there, then just do a copy through the JavaScript API. Or you could try the default copy action which is available

Comment: Ok, I'll check that. Thanks a lot.